# How can I install node.js?

Tags: chroot, nodejs

I have a chromebook with a Precise Ubuntu chroot on it.

I can't figure out how to install the current node.js from the tarball, because

```
./install
make
sudo make install
```

doesn't work.

Comment: What error message do you have ?

Comment: `./install` is just not a file.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to compile nodejs?

Comment: @hg8 I have a few things to do that I need to install it for.

Comment: So using apt-get is not okay for you?

Comment: @hg8 It would probably work.  I didn't know you could apt-get node.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to compile NodeJS by yourself. The easiest way to install NodeJS is using the official PPA (which contains the latest version — 4.2.4 as of today).

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and :

1. Install `curl`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install curl
   ```
2. Install NodeJS :

   ```
   curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo bash -
   sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
   ```

That's it!